# Does the order of the constant operand with any arithmetic operator affect optimization?

Tags: c++, assembly, optimization, c++17, compiler-optimization

Assume we define `const` or `constexpr` and we do simple arithmetic operator, several times, also *variables and function calls won't express or return constants*.

```
    #define NU = 3; //Macro or
    const int NU = 3 // general declaration or constexpr
    auto NU = []()constexpr -> int { return 3;}
    int result = 0;

   #Approach one -> const NU on left side of the operator right side could be function call or a function parameter
    for(int i = 0; i< SOME_MAX; ++i) result = NU * foo(); // function call or
    for(int i = 0; i< SOME_MAX; ++i) result = NU * var; // variable

   #Approach two -> const NU on Right side of the operator Left side could be function call or a function parameter
    for(int i = 0; i< SOME_MAX; ++i) result = foo() * NU ;// function call or
    for(int i = 0; i< SOME_MAX; ++i) result = var * NU; // variable
```

Which approach will generate optimized assembly -> machine code?

*Whether constant operand to be on LHS or RHS respect to the arithmetic operator will affect the **optimization** or **performance**?*

Note - Here I used it for picture the idea I have , the performance hit or in-efficiency could be negligible but, assume set of complex mathematical operations using bunch of constants.

Thanks.

Comment: Such micro-optimizations should rarely or ever be needed. Please take some time to read about [how to ask good questions](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), as well as [this question checklist](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2012/11/24/stack-overflow-question-checklist/), and about [the XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). Then please edit your question to include what problem you try to solve, why you need this, or if this is just for pure curiosity.

Comment: Also note that such micro-optimizations tend to be very compiler-specific (and maybe even very version of the compiler specific).

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude I just wanted to know if there any Optimizer theory behind it  or not?

Comment: If you want to find out, you can try your compiler on [Compiler Explorer](https://gcc.godbolt.org/). (Not that I expect significant differences if any.)

Comment: Btw.: `#define NU = 3;` => `#define NU 3`.

Comment: @Scheff thanks for editing and I totally forget about it, thank you very much about reminding it.

Comment: The C++ language standard is not concerned with optimisations and performance. Your compiler is. Try and see what it does with your real code (not toy examples). Observe performance of the resulting machine code. *If it is not enough for your purposes*, ask what can be done to improve it.

Comment: Your specific example code only uses the last value, though - unless the variable is declared volatile, the compiler eliminates the loops completely (except for the functions, which might have side effects)

Comment: @Hulk sorry about that, I just wanted to picture the constant operand order thingy , I missed the thing you mentioned.my bad.

Comment: @All https://godbolt.org why this happen in MSVC ?

Comment: MSVC makes a mess because @Scheff's link was silly: MSVC doesn't support `-O3` or `/O3` so it ignores it and compiles in debug mode.  Use `-O2` or `-Ox` for full optimization with MSVC.  (But `-O3` for full optimization with gcc or clang).  https://gcc.godbolt.org/z/lwa5xz shows MSVC working as expected: `mov edx, 9` for `NU() * 3`.

Comment: @PeterCordes Oops, my fault.

Comment: Here we go: [Compiler Explorer](https://gcc.godbolt.org/z/M-R5tY).All variants of NU resulted in a `mov esi, 3` (gcc `-O3`) or `mov edx, 3` (MSVC `/O2`).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It should be the same. **Most Modern** compilers will evaluate and propagate constants at compile time. The theory is called [Constant folding](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Constant_folding) or Constant Propagation.

EDIT: In terms of which side, it should not be a different. Although, I think in theorem provers, like coq, it is more difficult to prove RHS optimisations then LHS optimisations (or maybe the other way around... I forgot.).

Comment: Thanks for the reply Bar Stool,
Could you go thru this -> https://godbolt.org/z/Y7kONZ , switch to different compilers and see generated out put , MSVC the worst I got so far.
check iCCx64,clang,arm,gcc for instance :)

Comment: Do you find something strange?

Comment: It seems that MSVC only does 1 round of constant folding so it still multiplies the first constants.

Comment: I think [this](https://godbolt.org/z/-AIEJ1) one interesting. clang will even fold down loops for you :)

Comment: @BarStool: MSVC `-O3` is an unknown option that gets ignored; you're looking at debug mode output!  You want `-O2` or `-Ox` for MSVC full optimization, unlike `-O3` for gcc/clang (plus `-march=native` if your binary only needs to run locally.)  https://gcc.godbolt.org/z/lwa5xz